# Text changes aspect when input is focused, how can I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, input, text, fonts

When focussing on my `<input>`, the text seems to get thinner.. It only seems to happen when the `background-color` is dark in combination with a few specific text colors.

```html
<body style="background-color: black">
  <input type="text" />
  <span style="color: blue">TESTANDO</span>
</body>
```

Input **without** focus:
[image: Without Focus]

Input **with** focus:
[image: With Focus]

Changing the font or setting a font weight doesn't have any effect on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by removing the outline when the input is focused  `input:focus {outline: 0}`.

```css
input:focus {outline: 0}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black">
  <input type="text" />
  <span style="color: blue">TESTANDO</span>
</body>
```

If you want the outline, add it back with `box-shadow`

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0.5px #fff;  border-radius: 3px;`